# Image Classification Model not Improving with Pytorch pre-trained models

Tags: pytorch, resnet, torchvision, image-classification, vgg-net

I'm doing Image Classification on https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/muratkokludataset/grapevine-leaves-image-dataset dataset.
Grapevine leaves dataset with 5 classes and 100 images each.
I am experimenting with different torchvision models :[resnet, alexnet, vgg, squeezenet, densenet, inception].

but whatever use train and val accuracy in not improving.
[Model Training Image !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKjGt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtOAJ.png)

I'm following this tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html

### Epoch 47/50

train Loss: 1.6279 Acc: 0.1900
val Loss: 1.6099 Acc: 0.2500

### Epoch 48/50

train Loss: 1.6299 Acc: 0.1825
val Loss: 1.6101 Acc: 0.2500

### Epoch 49/50

train Loss: 1.6264 Acc: 0.2225
val Loss: 1.6116 Acc: 0.2500

### Epoch 50/50

train Loss: 1.5996 Acc: 0.2525
val Loss: 1.6108 Acc: 0.2500

Training complete in 4m 20s
Best val Acc: 0.250000

Answer (score 0):

I tried your dataset and I couldn't see any trouble with the loss not decreasing.

I used Pytorch through the FastAI library v2.
I achieved 92% accuracy on the validation set (only 100 images, split 80/20 on the dataset).

I tried resnet18 and resnet50 and both gave me common behaviour.
I don't think the problem you see is related to the model at all.

However, I can see at least two problems that you might have.

1. Your dataset is really small. Using data augmentation would be a good idea.
2. There is no code so I am not sure about the training procedure you are using and what "tools". For example cycling learning rate, the loss function etc.

Please find below the code I used to train a model on your dataset.
Note: Windows 10, python 3.9, torch 2.0.0+cu117, torchvision 0.15.1+cu117, fastai 2.7.12

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
from nbdev.showdoc import *

set_seed(2)

tfms = aug_transforms(do_flip=True, flip_vert=True)
images_folder = "D:/FastAI/Grapevine_Leaves_Image_Dataset"
dataloader = ImageDataLoaders.from_folder(images_folder, valid_pct=0.2, num_workers=0, batch_tfms=tfms, bs=32)

learner = cnn_learner(dataloader, resnet50, metrics=error_rate).to_fp16()
learner.lr_find()
```

[image: Learning rate]

The advised learning rate is 5.7e-4 and I just used that for testing purpose.
Then:

```
learner.fit_one_cycle(10, lr_max=5.7e-4)
```

This gives us for 10 epochs the following results:

[image: Training results]

We can then plot the confusion matrix on the validation set:

```
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learner)
losses, indexes = interp.top_losses()
interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=60)
```

[image: Confusion matrix]

And we can see that we have eight samples from the validation set that are wrongly classified. 100-8 => 92% accuracy.

Comment: Here is the notebook:https://www.kaggle.com/code/abhi626pawar/grapevine-leaves-image-classification